# Mysql Server Gone Away Issue not solved

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an issue with mysql saying "Server gone away" with:

> **Error : PDOStatement::execute():** send of 200 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in  /var/www/html/ICBBroadcaster/Service/Repositories/MainRepo.php on line number 113

I could not solve the error by changing following parameter in the `my.cnf` (mysql configuration):

```
max_allowed_packet = 500M
wait_timeout=3600
```

Does anyone have experience with, or know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, after setting `max_allowed_packet = 500M` and `wait_timeout=3600` value make sure you restart your MySQL server.

In past i encounter same problem, my problem was i was executing around 900 insert,update and select query in minute, which was like this.

`insert into table_name values(valueone,valuetwo);
insert into table_name values(valueone,valuetwo);
insert into table_name values(valueone,valuetwo);`

so my solution was i done bunch insert and update something like this

`insert into table_name values(valueone,valuetwo),(valueone,valuetwo),(valueone,valuetwo);`

so if setting and restarting MySQL server,

`max_allowed_packet = 500M
wait_timeout=3600`

didn't solve your problem then i think `MainRepo.php` script have something which is making your db server not respond.

See [common reasons for the MySQL server has gone away error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html)